# 'make install' compains libstdc++.so.6 not having GLIBCXX_3.4.15 but I have libstdc++.so.6 file in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: gcc, cmake, linker, glibc

on Centos 6.9, I am building cmake 3.5.0.  I have existing cmake 3.4.3 installed.  For 3.5.0, I did make ok, then did 'sudo make install'. But it gives me :

```
/home/ckim/CARLA/carla/cmake-3.5.0/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /home/ckim/CARLA/carla/cmake-3.5.0/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake)
/home/ckim/CARLA/carla/cmake-3.5.0/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/ckim/CARLA/carla/cmake-3.5.0/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake)
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

But I have /usr/local/lib64 before /usr/lib64 in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and the /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 has GLIBC_3.4.15 and GLIBC_3.5.21.

```
ckim@stph45:~/CARLA/carla/cmake-3.5.0] strings /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: gcc or ld do not look in /usr/local/lib64. It is not a standard place to search. Only /usr/local/lib is. It would also be very wrong to link with libstdc++ you didn't compile against.

Comment: Oh, I remember it now. I know I can use 'gcc -v' to see default link library paths. But do you know what link library paths cmake use? (I found this make install uses cmake)

Comment: Cmake by itself uses nothing at all.

Comment: that's strange. I found if I just run 'make install', it compiles ok, but just the file write permission error in some system directories. So I did  'sudo chmod go+w' to /usr/local/doc, /usr/local/share, /usr/local/bin with -'fR' option. Then the 'make install' finished without error.

Comment: so the library linking error occurred only when I do it with root prievilege.

Comment: This does look strange but there's not enough data to diagnose the exact problem.

Comment: @n.m oh, I confused clang with cmake in my previous comment. I wanted to know the default library path of clang and it was just 'clang -v'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I have /usr/local/lib64 before /usr/lib64 in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

When you run under `sudo`, GLIBC will ignore `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and only use *system* paths to search for libraries.

If GLIBC didn't do that, you could trivially compromise any `setuid` program by pointing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to your own `libc.so.6`.

Solutions:

1. Better: don't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Instead compile your programs with  appropriate `-rpath=` linker option, so they just work.
2. Worse: `sudo -s`.
   Now set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` any way you want, then run `make install`.